# Help making nicely centered columns with images of varying ratios

Tags: html, css, embed

I'm trying to make three columns with the titles "Friday", "Saturday", and "Sunday". Each column will have a series of images that are embedded via embedly (which end up as `<img>` tags where I have `a href` in case you're wondering).

I'm having trouble getting the images to center nicely directly underneath the column headers because the images are different aspect ratios (not sure if I'm using the term correctly).

For example [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/amandarykoff/5748058467/) picture is much wider than [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/amandarykoff/4732779602/) picture.

Here is my code so far.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Friday</th>
        <th>Saturday</th>
        <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="featuredGame">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/amandarykoff/5748058467/"></a>
                <p> Subway Series </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="featuredGame">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/amandarykoff/4732779602/"></a>
                <p> Subway Series </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="featuredGame">
                        <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/5chw4r7z/3559678190/"></a>
                        <p> Subway Series </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="featuredGame">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/adamzalaznik/4524246710/"></a>
                <p> Subway Series </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="featuredGame">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/24793373@N07/3823565546/"></a>
                <p> Subway Series </p>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="featuredGame">
                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/unbirthdayparty/5738164359/"></a>
                <p> Subway Series </p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And the css for `featuredGame`:

**NOTE** the `#featured` tag is intentional. This table is encased within `<div id="featured">`

```
#featured .featuredGame {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 1.0em;   
}

th td {text-align:center;}
```

Comment: What does embedly do with the anchor elements? Replace them with image elements? iframes?

Comment: @Brent img elements. I mentioned that in my OP.

Comment: The row with the days should really be wrapped in a [<thead>](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/thead)

Comment: @joshb I added that though it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Tory It doesn't just a matter of semantics.

Comment: @Tory, I just wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
th td {text-align:center;}
```

to

```
th, td {text-align:center;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/ubmW3/

Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 2):

In you css block put
 `margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;`
that should center it

Comment: that kinda worked... The column headers are on the right end of the column still.

Comment: i dont think you need the float left and try adding this to your css file:  
th td {text-align:center;}

Comment: removed float, added the css. The column titles are now a little closer but still well off to the right side.

Comment: @Tory Didn't see that the "th td" style was added from this comment. They need to be separated by a comma. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. your style rule is trying to apply styles to an element with an `id="featured"` AND a `class="featuredGame`.  That's part of the reason it is failing.  (At least without the embedly.)  Remove the `id` and the styles start to work.
2. The images are very large  Does embedly shrink them?  If not, your table design will not hold them well in a standard resolution browser.

Comment: all good points, I should mention this is all encased within a `<div id="featured">`. Yes, embedly shrinks them down to any size I want. I have them in thumbnail sizes.